# Automatically adding missing resx files in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, localization, resx

I have a solution which has approximately 30 win forms in it. These forms need to be localized for three other languages. I have written an application which generates resx files for these languages for the windows forms.

Now I have 90 resx files generated and located at the same place where their original resx files reside. What I want is not to add these existing resources manually.

Is there any way to add these existing resources at once in Visual studio or somehow programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Programatically you're probably looking at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.addfromfile(v=vs.100).aspx